# Maximum value of the PID in QNX

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

Do you know what is the maximum value of Process ID both in 32-bit and 64-bit QNX systems and if there is a header where it is defined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value for a pid_t in QNX is the largest positive integer representable in that type.  For QNX 6.x, where pid_t == int32_t, that would be INT_MAX from <limits.h>.   I don't have QNX 7.x handy to check, so you'll have to check the definition (try <sys/target_nto.h>) to find out what's being used there.

Comment: Still INT_MAX also in QNX 7.x. Thank you very much.